# Pass gcm Registration Id from GCMBaseIntentService class to MainActivity via Interface in android

Tags: java, android, interface, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I create a Interface to pass gcm id from `GCMBaseIntentService` class to my Application `MainActivity`.

My Interface is ::

```
public interface GcmId {
    public void sendGcm(String id);
}
```

How can call this interface in `GCMBaseIntentService` class and pass it in `MainActivity` Interface implemention.

Thanks

Comment: Try to pass reference of your MainActivity to  GCMBaseIntentService and pass your id via interface implementation using this reference.

Comment: it is ok , if i go from MainActivity to other activity then it is working..

Comment: then set other activity reference to GCMBaseIntentService using static method in GCMBaseIntentService.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating complicated ways to pass the registration ID from your intent service to your activity, you can store it in SharedPreferences, and access it where ever it is needed.

Even better, you don't have to use GCMBaseIntentService, which is a deprecated class. You can use the new synchronized registration method `GoogleCloudMessaging.register()`, which you can call in your main activity (though you should run it in the background), and get the result without involving any broadcast receiver or intent service.

Comment: Thanks, for you answer but i want to do it in this way. it is possible or not ? ,if possible then way?